# React.js как подключить json файл с данными?

Tags: javascript, json

Здравствуйте, недавно начал осваивать реакт, так что заранее прошу прощения за глупость этого вопроса.

Как подключить локальный файл `libraries.json` с названием библиотек, вот сам код:

```
var MenuExample = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { focused: 0 };
    },

    clicked: function(index){



        this.setState({focused: index});
    },

    render: function() {



        var self = this;



        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{ this.props.items.map(function(m, index){

                    var style = '';

                    if(self.state.focused == index){
                        style = 'focused';
                    }



                    return <li className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;

                }) }

                </ul>

                <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p>
            </div>
        );

    }
});



React.renderComponent(
    <MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
    document.body
);
).

/** @jsx React.DOM */



var SearchExample = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { searchString: '' };
    },

    handleChange: function(e){


        this.setState({searchString:e.target.value});
    },

    render: function() {

        var libraries = this.props.items,
            searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();


        if(searchString.length > 0){

            // Ищем. Фильтрируем резальтаты.

            libraries = libraries.filter(function(l){
                return l.name.toLowerCase().match( searchString );
            });

        }

        return <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type here" />

                    <ul>

                        { libraries.map(function(l){
                            return <li>{l.name} <a href={l.url}>{l.url}</a></li>
                        }) }

                    </ul>

                </div>;

    }
});


var libraries = [

    { name: 'Backbone.js', url: 'http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/'},
    { name: 'AngularJS', url: 'https://angularjs.org/'},
    { name: 'jQuery', url: 'http://jquery.com/'},
    { name: 'Prototype', url: 'http://www.prototypejs.org/'},
    { name: 'React', url: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/'},
    { name: 'Ember', url: 'http://emberjs.com/'},
    { name: 'Knockout.js', url: 'http://knockoutjs.com/'},
    { name: 'Dojo', url: 'http://dojotoolkit.org/'},
    { name: 'Mootools', url: 'http://mootools.net/'},
    { name: 'Underscore', url: 'http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/'},
    { name: 'Lodash', url: 'http://lodash.com/'},
    { name: 'Moment', url: 'http://momentjs.com/'},
    { name: 'Express', url: 'http://expressjs.com/'},
    { name: 'Koa', url: 'http://koajs.com/'},

];



React.renderComponent(
    <SearchExample items={ libraries } />,
    document.body
);
```

Т.е. подгружать в переменную `libraries` json-файл с названиями этих библиотек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его можно подключить так

```
var libraries = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./libraries.json'));
```

и дальше работать как с простым JSON, но невидя самого JSON сложно сказать будет то что ожидае